# How to cache WMS-image layers

Tags: openlayers, wms, openlayers-5

I preloaded images having urls containing a GetMap request (like below) into an IMG tag having width/height of 0px and set display to 'none'. 
The difference between the url of each image is only the "TIME" part (e.g. 'TIME=2019-04-05T05:40:00.000Z'). In FireFox inspect I can see each image being downloaded.

Example of an url:
https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/wms?version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png; mode=8bit&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=dwd:RX-Produkt&TIME=2019-04-05T05:40:00.000Z&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=407&HEIGHT=406&BBOX=697105.6892639723,6166327.945821739,1692621.5456501078,7159397.8173027495

Preloading (in case of loading only one timestep):

```
$('<img />')
   .attr('id', 'img1')
     .attr('src', URL)
     .appendTo('div#map-1')
     .css({
         'position': 'relative',
         'display': 'none',
         'height': 0,
         'width': 0
     })
  ;
```

If I load a WMS-layer and now change the source of it by hovering over a timeline (each hover changes only the time-part of the url of the WMS-layer) the resulting png from the WMS server is being downloaded from the WMS-server once again (although the url is exactly the same as when preloaded).

Screendump of my website: https://www.kambeel.nl/data/wms.png

Each mouseover of a time/date results in triggering this (where TIME is a ISO8601 timestamp and LYR is the name of the layer):

```
window['WMS-1'].getSource().updateParams({'LAYERS': LYR, 'TIME': Time});
```

When looking into Firefox inspect I can see the pngs, with exactly the same URL as when preloading, being downloaded again.

How can I prevent the re-downloading from these png's??

Comment: If there is no cache-control header in the response from the remote server you could consider using a proxy on your own server to allow browsers to cache.

Comment: Don't think I'm able to use a proxy server on the companies website....;-)

Caching/preloading non-WMS layers is working......will look further into WMS ....... thanks for pointing me to this option btw!!